# What does straight mean in this sentence "his answers sounded straight from ..."

Tags: word-meaning

What does **straight** mean in this sentence "The 40-year-old Chew was funny and relaxed for most of the interview, even if many of *his answers sounded straight from* the 2010s Mark Zuckerberg / Jack Dorsey social networking is good for the world playbook. ", quote from "[TikTok CEO Shou Zi Chew explains how US data will be kept out of China](https://www.theverge.com/2022/11/30/23486771/tiktok-ceo-shou-zi-chew-data-protection-us-users)"

I look up straight from several dictionaries but can't find a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is an adverb in this context and means "directly", and without modification.  Compare this to the expression "straight from the horses mouth". Cambridge has the example "The valentine comes straight from my heart"

Comment: So does that sentence mean his answers were just like what Mark Zuckerberg / Jack Dorsey had said in 2010 ?

Comment: They were just like _the kind of thing_ MZ and JD used to say.

Answer (score 0):

As already previously mentionned, "straight", although having multiple possible meanings, depending on usage and context, is here used as an adverb, referring to the manner in which it regards to "the 2010s Mark Zuckerberg [...]". It implies "totally like", "in the same fashion as", or "in the same way than".